# Como manter AppBar e BottomNavigationBar entre páginas

Tags: flutter

gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês em um App em Flutter.
Estou criando as rotas nomeadas para fazer a navegação entre as páginas do App.
Porém, não consegui manter a AppBar e o BottomNavigationBar durante a navegação.
Sempre direciona pra uma nova tela, gostaria de manter o header e o footer do App sem repetir o código nos arquivos dart.
É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando o `BottomNavigationBar` você não irá chamar as telas pelo `Navigation` da forma normal, você poderia usar por exemplo uma `TabView` ou um `PageView` para alterar entre suas telas.

Veja um exemplo *(Uma das formas de se fazer)*

> Declaração da sua tela principal

```
 class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    TelaFeedNoticias(),
    TelaConfiguracoes(),
    TelaInformacoesAdicionais()
  ];
```

> Corpo da sua tela principal

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('My Flutter App'),
     ),
     body: _children[_currentIndex],
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       onTap: onTabTapped,
       currentIndex: _currentIndex,
       items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.home),
           title: Text('Home'),
         ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
           title: Text('Messages'),
         ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.person),
           title: Text('Profile')
         )
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
```

> Onde a mágica de alterar entre as telas acontece

```
void onTabTapped(int index) {
   setState(() {
     _currentIndex = index;
   });
 }
```

*Font: https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation*

Explicando: Ao clicar em cada item da sua `NavigationBottomBar`, será executado o método `OnTabTapped(int index)` e esse por sua vez, por meio do `setState()`, irá reconstruir sua estrutura com o novo index, assim selecionando a tela referida na lista `_children`.
Desta forma sua aplicação irá abrir a tela selecionada dentro da sua tela principal e o seu `NavigationBottomBar` e `AppBar` será mantido.

Essa é apenas uma forma de se fazer, daí você vai brincando com as possibilidades.

Obs.: Você pode criar as outras telas da forma normal, com o `StateFulWidget` ou `StateLessWidget`, depois basta referenciá-las na lista `_children`.